# Randomizing orders in a GA population not working properly in Lua

Tags: lua, genetic-algorithm

I'm new to using Lua, and I'm creating a TSP solution in Lua using a genetic algorithm, but the function to randomize the orders of the population seems to be overwriting other orders. Every time a new order loops through the randomizer, it does randomize its order differently than all previous orders, but it also sets all previous orders equal to itself.

I've debugged to localize the problem, and I'm positive that's what's happening, but no matter how many times I go over it I can't logically figure out why. Is there a glaringly obvious thing I'm missing?

Just showing that the tables are being properly created and the randomizer seed is set.

```
order = {}
population = {}
math.randomseed(os.time())
```

Here's the swap and shuffle functions being used. They should be working properly based on my tests, but it's always possible I missed something.

```
function swap(tbl, i, j)
  tbl[i], tbl[j] = tbl[j], tbl[i]
end

function shuffle(tbl)
  for i = #tbl, 2, -1 do
    local j = math.random(#tbl)
    swap(tbl, i, j)
  end
  return tbl
end
```

Setting the initial order

```
for i = 1, 10 do
  order[i] = i
end
```

This is likely the problem area

```
for i = 1, 10 do
  population[i] = order
  shuffle(population[i])
end
```

What should be happening here is that the initial order should be set as a basic 1 through 10, then the next loop should fill the population with 10 different randomized orders. Instead, the second loop is assigning the first table to a random order, then the next time it loops through it apparently sets the next order and all orders before it to a new random order, making them all equal to each other by the time the loop finishes.

I have checked the shuffle and swap functions in controlled environments and am sure they are working properly. Additionally, the initial order is being properly set.

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is due to how a lua handles tables.

Here is an example:

```
tbl1 = {}
tbl2 = tbl1

tbl2[1] = 1

print(tbl1[1])
```

The result is that `tbl1[1]` prints `1`. This is because `tbl2` and `tbl1` are the **same** table just by different names.

This is what you are experiencing when you make `population[i] = order` you only have **1** table by **10** different names.

To avoid this you can copy the table. here is a resources on table coping:

> http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable

The quickest way to adjust your code would be to do:

```
for i = 1, 10 do
  population[i] = {table.unpack(order)}
  shuffle(population[i])
end
```

This method only works with sequential numeric indices

> https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack

---

Alternatively you can avoid the whole process by creating a function to initialize your order:

```
function init_order()
    local order = {}

    for i = 1, 10 do
        order[i] = i
    end

    return order
end
```

then call the function in your for loop:

```
for i = 1, 10 do
  population[i] = init_order()
  shuffle(population[i])
end
```